# generate xml by only knowing the element name and his parent

Tags: java, xml

I want to generate an xml file, as said in the title. The data that I need is stored in a database table in the form `XML_NAME` and `XML_PARENT_NAME`, which is the parent for `XML_NAME`.

Now, can you give me some ideas, algorithms, how to generate my xml file by only knowing these two things ?

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:
XML Example:

```
<root>
  <element1></element1>
  <element2></element2>
  <element3>
    <child>
      <text></text>
    </child>
  </element3>
</root>
```

Database model:

```
XML_NAME | XML_PARENT_NAME
root  
element1   root
element2   root
element3   root
child      element3
text       child
```

I only have this DB entries and from these ones I need to costruct an xml file, which loooks like the above one.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you provide more information about the XML you need?

Comment: I'm working on it now. The xml looks like a normal one, there is nothing specific. It does not need to have any values inside, just the tags. The database table looks like this;

XML_NAME | XML_PARENT_NAME
Total            | Report
TotalIncome | Total
TotalInvest   | Total ... and so on

Comment: I am not sure what a "normal one" means. Are you looking to do: `<parent_name><xml_name><total>123</total><totalIncome>987</totalIncome></xml_name><parent_name>`

Comment: Ok. I've edited my post. I think it's a little more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an algorithm that's easy to implement, assuming that you have a simple result set retrieved from the database, which contains the two columns you mentioned.

1. Loop through all records first and construct an XML Node object for each XML_NAME name (put the XML Node objects in a List).
2. Create a HashMap with String keys (XML_NAME name) and XML Node objects as values. Add each XML Node as an entry into this map.
3. Loop through all records again (only once) and for each XML_NAME - XML_PARENT_NAME pair, look up both XML Node objects in the map. Add the XML Node of the former to the list of child nodes for the latter.
4. Create a root XML Node. Loop through the list of XML Nodes and add each node which doesn't have a parent to this root node, as a child of the root node.
5. Convert the root XML Node to String or do whatever you want with it.

Comment: I think this would work. Thank you. You said in step 2.) to create a map with a string key. What key actually ?

Comment: The XML_NAME name. Edited the answer to include this.

Answer (score 0):

Using XML Stream writer:

Here is a simple example that writes a series of events to disk, using a FileWriter:

```
XMLOutputFactory factory      = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();
try {
 XMLStreamWriter writer = factory.createXMLStreamWriter(
         new     FileWriter("data\\output2.xml"));

writer.writeStartDocument();
      writer.writeStartElement("document");
writer.writeStartElement("data");
writer.writeAttribute("name", "value");
writer.writeEndElement();
writer.writeEndElement();
 writer.writeEndDocument();

 writer.flush();
 writer.close();
} catch (XMLStreamException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The result of executing this code is the following XML file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<document><data name="value"></data>    </document>
```

Ref:http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-xml/stax-xmlstreamwriter.html

If you dont need values just use writeStartElement and writeEndElement

Also another option with child elements is:

```
Element root=new Element("CONFIGURATION");
Document doc=new Document();
Element child1=new Element("BROWSER");
child1.addContent("chrome");
Element child2=new Element("BASE");
child1.addContent("http:fut");
Element child3=new Element("EMPLOYEE");
child3.addContent(new     Element("EMP_NAME").addContent("Anhorn, Irene"));

root.addContent(child1);
root.addContent(child2);
root.addContent(child3);

doc.setRootElement(root);

XMLOutputter outter=new XMLOutputter();
outter.setFormat(Format.getPrettyFormat());
outter.output(doc, new FileWriter(new     File("myxml.xml")));
```

Comment: I think the question was not how to actually write the XML to a file - I think OP knows that - but how to construct the XML node structure with the result set from his database table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an algorithm which @mlkammer suggested.

After collecting final map which contains all info you can write it to file.

For an example, your map looks as `Map<String, List<String>> map`.

After it, you can easily format and write it to file.

Here is ***code snippet***:

```
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import org.w3c.dom.ls.DOMImplementationLS;
import org.w3c.dom.ls.LSSerializer;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.*;

public class XmlBuilder {

    private DocumentBuilder builder;

    private Document doc;

    /**
     * Constructs an item list builder.
     *
     * @throws CreateDocumentConfigurationException
     */
    public XmlBuilder() throws CreateDocumentConfigurationException {
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            throw new CreateDocumentConfigurationException("exception create new document", e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Builds a DOM document for an array list of items.
     *
     * @param elementMap map of items.
     * @return a DOM document describing the items.
     */
    public Document build(Map<String, List<String>> elementMap) {
        doc = builder.newDocument();
        doc.appendChild(createItems(elementMap));
        return doc;
    }

    /**
     * Builds a DOM element for an array list of items.
     *
     * @param elementMap the map of items
     * @return a DOM element describing the items
     */
    private Element createItems(Map<String, List<String>> elementMap) {
        Element e = null;
        for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> anItem : elementMap.entrySet()) {
            e = doc.createElement(anItem.getKey());
            for (Node node : createItemsList(anItem.getValue())) {
                e.appendChild(node);
            }
        }
        return e;
    }

    private List<Node> createItemsList(List<String> items) {
        List<Node> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String item : items) {
            Element item1 = createItem(item);
            result.add(item1);
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Builds a DOM element for an item.
     *
     * @param anItem the item
     * @return a DOM element describing the item
     */
    private Element createItem(String anItem) {
        // if you need some text element to your element - just append it here.
        return doc.createElement(anItem);
    }

    /**
     * Builds the text content for document
     *
     * @param name element
     * @param text content
     * @return text element
     */
    private Element createTextElement(String name, String text) {
        Text t = doc.createTextNode(text);
        Element e = doc.createElement(name);
        e.appendChild(t);
        return e;
    }


    private String generateXmlContent(Map<String, List<String>> elementMap) {
        String content;

        Document doc = build(elementMap);
        DOMImplementation impl = doc.getImplementation();
        DOMImplementationLS implLS = (DOMImplementationLS) impl.getFeature("LS", "3.0");

        LSSerializer ser = implLS.createLSSerializer();
        ser.getDomConfig().setParameter("format-pretty-print", true);
        content = ser.writeToString(doc);

        return content;
    }

    public void writeToXmlFile(String xmlContent) {
        File theDir = new File("./output");
        if (!theDir.exists())
            theDir.mkdir();

        String fileName = "./output/" + this.getClass().getSimpleName() + "_"
                + Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + ".xml";

        try (OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(new File(fileName))) {
            try (OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(stream, StandardCharsets.UTF_16)) {
                out.write(xmlContent);
                out.write("\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println("Cannot write to file!" + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws CreateDocumentConfigurationException {
        XmlBuilder xmlBuilder = new XmlBuilder();
        Map<String, List<String>> map = MapFactory.mapOf(MapFactory.entry("root", Arrays.asList("element1", "element2", "element3")));

        String xmlContent = xmlBuilder.generateXmlContent(map);
        xmlBuilder.writeToXmlFile(xmlContent);
    }
}
```

***Output after execution*** will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<root>
    <element1/>
    <element2/>
    <element3/>
</root>
```